# Initializing an object in a method in Java

Tags: java, initialization, pass-by-reference

Suppose I want to have a bunch of private static objects in a class, but they are complicated objects and I would like to use a specific function to initialize them with some parameters. Ideally, I would write code like this:

```
public class TestClass{
    private Class ComplicatedObject{
        private int anInteger;
        private String aString;
        public ComplicatedObject(int inputInt,String inputString){
             anInteger = inputInt;
             aString = inputString;
        }
        public void someMethod(){
            //do a thing
        }
    }
    private void MakeAThing(ComplicatedObject theThing, int someInt,int someString){
        theThing = new ComplicatedObject(someInt,someString);
        //do extra stuff that one might want to do here
    }
    private static ComplicatedObject IMPORTANT_OBJECT;
    public TestClass(){
         MakeAThing(IMPORTANT_OBJECT, 0,"Test");
         IMPORTANT_OBJECT.someMethod();
    }
}
```

This will crash because (as far as I understand Java) when I call `someMethod()` on `IMPORTANT_OBJECT`, `IMPORTANT_OBJECT` is actually null - the `MakeAThing` method did create a new object, but only its internal reference (`theThing`) actually referenced the new object. The reference for `IMPORTANT_OBJECT` is still null.

Is there any way I can write a method that will change the reference for `IMPORTANT_OBJECT` to reference a new object?

(yes, I know that one easy solution would be to just say `IMPORTANT_OBJECT = new Object();` and then add the parameters later, but this will make my code really messy (there are many "important objects") and if there is another way I'd much prefer it.)

Comment: There is no constructor for `Object` that has parameters.  Your question is very unclear. Please update your question to include a [mcve].  I.e. code that actually compiles.

Comment: `private static IMPORTANT_OBJECT;` You need to define a type at compilation, otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: This code should not compile, cause there is not datatype of IMPORT_OBJECT

Comment: Instead of `theThing`, change it to `IMPORTANT_OBJECT` and remove the first parameter of `TestClass#MakeAThing`.

Comment: Are these arguments to `MakeAThing` going to not depend on anything in the `TestClass` constructor like in your example? If so, why not just make `MakeAThing` return the object and just initialize `IMPORTANT_OBJECT` directly in the declaration: `private static ComplicatedObject IMPORTANT_OBJECT = MakeAThing(...);`. If the arguments depend on something in the `TestClass` constructor, then how do you know that two invocations of the `TestClass` constructor won't give different arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about function that return new ComplicatedObject:

```
private ComplicatedObject MakeAThing(int someInt,int someString){
    return new ComplicatedObject(someInt,someString);
}
```

And just initialize the IMPORTANT_OBJECT in TestClass constructor

```
public TestClass(){
     IMPORTANT_OBJECT = (0,"Test");
     IMPORTANT_OBJECT.someMethod();
}
```

Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: That works, sort of. Part of the issue was that there would be cases where `IMPORTANT_OBJECT` was already initialized and didn't need to be initialized again, but that could be solved by something like `if (null!=IMPORTANT_OBJECT) return IMPORTANT_OBJECT;`.